# PostgreSQL database synchronization

Tags: postgresql

My company has two locations: Head Quarters (HQ) and a sub location (SL).Both locations (HQ and SL) has separate PostgreSQL(9.6) databases with the same schema and they will do transactions (insert/delete/update) in off-line. When both comes on line, both databases need to be synchronized (ie, come in the same state). Is it possible?

Comment: How do you intend to resolve conflicts? Is your application designed with this in mind? There is no out-of-the-box solution for this, and it is not simple.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a some configuration setting you can just turn on? No.

Is it possible at all? Yes, you could write something to do it but this is going to be vary schema-specific and probably isn't actually something you're going to want:

The problem with what you're proposing is unique columns (including primary keys and serial columns): how do you resolve conflicts between HQ and SL?

Maybe HQ always wins. If there's a conflict between the two we just delete the row in SL.

Maybe there is some part of all unique columns to designate which it came from.

Maybe you just have it flagged and an operator manually deals with it. (this is how Lotus Domino handles the situation)

All of these are going to require information about how the data is being used, that postgres just doesn't have. Because of that managing this resync will likely have to be done by your own custom code, and you'd have to be extremely careful about how it manages it.

EDIT: **As Keven points out below, trying to do this is probably a recipe for disaster, if you at all care about consistency.**

Comment: Another point: If you care about consistency, you won't build a system like this in the first place.  If you *don't* care about consistency, then you don't need the overhead of Postgres and can use something lighter like a NoSQL database.

Comment: Definitely agree, Kevin. Personally, I use postgres to validate everything that goes into my database, to the best of my ability. Trying to fix bunk data is no fun.